# AngularJs How to have multiple Views (more than 2) and each view have more than one state( using tabs)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create one html page using AngularJs with multiple views. And each view have nested states. When I am trying to use two view with nested states. It's only displaying one. Please tell me if I can use any particular steps or any link. It will be really helpful.

I have folder structure like shown in the attached image[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmql0.png).

--Trying to add three child views into Parent-folder.html

[A little view of what I am trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRdg7.png)

Answer (score 0):

The following link will be helpful to explore nested state in angular ui router
[multiple states by name](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)